# How to programatically get the nested components from a Struts2 tag?

Tags: struts2, tags, nested

How can i get all the nested tag elements from a struts2 tag?
for instance **text and checkbox** tags from **form** tag?:

```
<s:form>
 <s:text .../>
 <s:checkbox .../
<s:form>
```

I know that form is a tag defined in `strust-tags.tld` and it extends the `org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.FormTag`, 
but how does it goes behind the scene to get the nested tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use getComponentStack() method from the org.apache.struts2.components.Component class.